# The JPG file on my Open Office document is blurry when exported to PDF

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, openoffice, jpeg

I have tried both Open Office and Word, and the issue is the same.  All looks fine until the document is exported to PDF, then the JPG image on the document becomes blurry.  I hope someone can help.

Comment: Did you happen to use a low quality setting while exporting to PDF? (like lower then 90%, see [this screen](http://i.imgur.com/NK7mv4B.png)) Perhaps you can create a sample PDF for us to look at.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rik. I checked and the quality setting was at 90%, so I put it up to 100%, and it is slightly better, but still quite blurry!

Comment: Are other PDF sharp? It could be your Adobe Reader is at a less then optimum setting for display. (hence my question for a sample PDF) You could play with [these settings](http://i.imgur.com/PbebVg1.png) in Adobe Reader.

Comment: I tried playing around with them settings, but it didn't help.  Sorry but I'm not sure how to attach a sample PDF?

Comment: You could use a service like [filehosting.org](http://www.filehosting.org/). The can post the link you get back here. (Also give a link to the original jpg so we can compare with our Open-Office version)

Comment: This is the example file:http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/438634/Example.pdf

Comment: And how sharp is the original jpg? This just looks like the original is low resolution (or you enlarged it in OpenOffice). BTW If it's just text you could better type that logo in text (with the right font), it will be as sharp as the other text in PDF. (Of course this will not work for real pictures.)

Comment: This is the Open Office version of the same file http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/438641/Example.odt

Comment: I don't have access to the font that was used in creating the logo, unfortunately!

Comment: If you zoom in (you can use Ctrl + wheel up to 500%), in the OpenOffice document you'll see the jpg is already very blurry. So this has nothing to do with converting it to PDF (where it stays just as blurry). You need to ask for a new document (or jpg) which is far sharper or ask for the font. This image is not suitable for stationery. (It almost looks like it's taken from the website)

Comment: @Rik, I would suggest to post your thoughts as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

After seeing the PDF with accompanying Open Office document it was clear the original image in Open Office was of low quality (96dpi). Too low to be used as stationery.

In Open Office it was not as clear as in the PDF because the page in Open Office is somewhat reduced in size on screen (with the borders). However when zooming in (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Mousewheel-up</kbd>), it was very clear. Creating a PDF from this does not improve the image.

When creating letters with stationery in Open Office it is best to use high quality images of at least [300dpi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch) and preferable [600dpi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch). Images from websites are usually only intended for display on screen and when used in documents tend to become blurry. **However**, you do have to find a good balance between image quality and final size of your document (You wouldn't want to E-mail a 4 Mb document every time) A final document of somewhere between 50kb to 300kb would be the most ideal.

Even better would be to use a .EPS file for the image with vector-information. That would be sharpest (and smallest in size) but the downside is you don't see the image on screen in Open Office (only when printing and exporting to PDF). You'll only see a "bounding"-box (placeholder for the image).

If the image only contains text (like in this case) it's also a good option to use the correct font and just type the text of the image in a textbox and move this textbox to the exact right place. This will also result in a small final document.